# Pass parameter from URL to Angular JS controller in laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can i get `fixassid` from `url` in `route history` to `angular js controller` and pass it to `getpc_his` in `controller`.

My Blade template

```
<a href="{{url('history/'.$get_history_pc->fixass_id)}}">( View History )</a>
```

My Route

```
Route::get('history/{fixassid}',function (){
        return view('assetmanagement.history.pchistory');
    });
Route::get('/api/v1/pchists/{fixassid}','HistoryController@getpc_his');
```

My Angular JS

```
var app = angular.module('angtable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
    .constant('API_URL', 'http://testing/mypro/public/api/v1/');
app.controller('pchistory', function ($scope, $http, API_URL) {
    $scope.currentPage=1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage=10;

    $scope.sizes = [ {code: 0, name: '5'}];
    $scope.update = function() {
        //console.log($scope.item.code, $scope.item.name)
        $scope.itemsPerPage= $scope.item.name;
    }

    //retrieve employees listing from API
    $http.get(API_URL + "pchists/"+ "fixassid")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.pchists = response;
        });

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }
});
```

My Controller

```
public function getpc_his($fixassid){       
        $history=DB::table('psl_tbl_his')           
            ->where('fixass_id',$fixassid)
            ->get();
        return $history;
}
```

Comment: Confusing what you are trying to do here

Comment: @charlietfl : i want to pass parameter from url in my first route to controller in angular js and then pass it to laravel controller

Comment: That is still confusing... parameter starting in javascript or back end?

Comment: @charlietfl : my angular js controller $http.get(API_URL + "pchists/"+ "fixassid") i want to get fixassid from my first route

Comment: @charlietfl you can guide me the way to pass it by javascript or by back end but now in my code i pass it by my laravel route Route::get('history/{fixassid}'

Comment: when i change my controller in angular js by put fixassid by value in DB i can get the result $http.get(API_URL + "pchists/"+ "PC-VJ89D34")

Comment: @charlietfl i think the value that i input will pass to laravel controller getpc_his($fixassid)